# Modifying t-test for character values

Tags: r

I am trying to run a Welch two-sided t-test on the following sample data frame:

```
structure(list(CellType = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("CellA", "CellB", "CellC"), class = "factor"), Gene1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Mut", "Wt"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```

I think the code might look something like this so I can run this t-test between specific Cell Types and Gene1 (having only binary values of Mutant vs Wild type):

```
t.test(Test$Gene1[Test$CellTypeT=="CellA"], 
                  Test$Gene1[Test$CellType=="CellB"])$p.value
```

However, this code doesn't work as is and might require conversion of text values (i.e. "Mut" and "Wt") into numeric values that can be recognized by the t-test function. Any suggestions on how I can remedy this situation? Thanks!

Comment: You cant do t-test with characters! A t-test is for difference in means. What would you like to know about your data?

Comment: Converting to numbers is easy, but completely wrong - the arbitrary choice of number will determine your result - you need a different test

Comment: @rg255 Thanks, can you recommend another test/code that can be used to test for statistical significance in this instance?

Comment: hey @Adam.. there is no such thing as "test for statistical significance", Most likely not something you wanna hear, you need to have a hypothesis, and then look for the statistical method that allows you to make the right inferences

Comment: maybe you can read this for a start: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/D_01.html

Comment: @Adam what is your data and what is your hypothesis?

Comment: @Adam are you trying to test the association between CellType and Gene1?